# Cannot assign value of type Double to type String

Tags: swift, string, xcode, type-conversion, double

trying to assign label text to 2 each textField inputs
warning show up says cannot assign value of type Double to type string

any suggestions

```
    @IBAction func percentage1button(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let firstValue = Double(percentage1textField1.text!)
        let secondValue = Double(percentage1textfield2.text!)
       
        let outputValue = Double(firstValue! + secondValue!)
        percentage1result.text = outputValue
    }
```

Comment: ```percentage1result.text = "\(outputValue)"```

Comment: You are trying to assign `Double` (outputValue) into `String` (.text). Do this: percentage1result.text = "\(outputValue)"

Comment: You might want a `NumberFormatter`? To decide how many decimals to show, separators, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I will also suggest you not to use force unwrap:

```
@IBAction func percentage1button(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let val1 = Double(percentage1textField1.text ?? ""),
          let val2 = Double(percentage1textfield2.text ?? "") else
    {
        return
    }
    let outputValue = val1 + val2
    percentage1result.text = "\(outputValue)"
}
```